# Apple watch face went blank after i put it on the charger

Tags: display, apple-watch

About to go for a walk, i put it on the charger even though it still had power. Instead of the usual indicator of remaining charge, a little green daisy appeared. Then the face went blank. I left it on the chargwr, then put it on my wrist. Face blank. When I put it back on the charger the usual ping occurred but no image. I still was notified that my watch unlocked my phone. I tried side button and digital crown but nothing occurred

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Have you tried to do a [force restart](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/restart-apple-watch-apd521a8a902/watchos)?